# exceute MSBuild XML file inside other MSBuild

Tags: xml, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I'm trying to create an automated build of all my projects,
some of my projects already have `MSBuild.xml` file which build those projects.

Is there an option to build those `MSBuild.xml` through other `MSbuild` file?

Comment: `<Msbuild Projects='MSBuild.xml' Targets='Build' />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
  <Target Name="BuildAnOutsideMSBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(WorkingCheckout)\Another_Solution_Or_CsProj_or_MsBuildFile.proj" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TargetOutputsItemName"></Output>
    </MSBuild>
    <Message Text="Build completed" />
  </Target>
```

If your "sub project" needs any kind of path (file names or folder names).. you can NOT send relative paths.
You must send the full path down.  (The one exception is if the parent.sln and the child.sln exist in the same directory..but that doesn't happen very often in my experience)

Something like this:

```
  <ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="..\"> <!-- Some relative path here -->
      <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="MyAbsolutionPathProperty"/>
    </ConvertToAbsolutePath>            
    <Message Text="'MyAbsolutionPathProperty' = '$(MyAbsolutionPathProperty)'" />
```

Now you can send "MyAbsolutionPathProperty" as a parameter to the "outside" MSBuild .proj.